# Android studio DDMS emulator control disable

Tags: android, emulation, ddms

I was tried to make app to use GPS or telephony call. I'm learning android programming, I'm beginner in this. And I have problem with DDMS emulator control, I can't change anything because is disable all functions with this.

I have Android studio 2.0 and when I installing API use API 23 (with Google API'es) Marshmallow 6.0.

I use this on MAC (OS X el capitan) but I have this problem also in Windows 10 on my PC.

Sorry for my bed English.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Android documentation ([here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html)), the emulation control tab in DDMS is no longer supported .
I'm currently using V2.1, but check if the android emulator itself has the functionality of the Emulation control Tab.([check this](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html))

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 16):

[image: Android emulator extended controls]

Location settings for the Android emulator are now part of the extended controls.

Comment: I do wish Google would place a note in the device monitor to this affect. Yet another GAAAGGH!!!! moment with Android.